# Updating maven project by command line

Tags: eclipse, maven

which is the equivalent from command line of the eclipse command: **Right click on project -> maven -> update project** ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Eclipse feature. There is no command line equivalent.

Maven projects don't need to be "updated", this is an Eclipse thing.

If you want to update Snapshots, though, you need to build with `-U` as mentioned in the answer of @DarkStar1.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what IDE that image/snippet comes from but my guess would be, it's equivalent to a `mvn clean install -U`